# Программа завершается с кодом 3221226356

Tags: c++, вектор

Видимо, не правильно обращаюсь с двумерными векторами.
P.S.Нужна матрица из двух столбцов

```
typedef vector< vector<string> > matrix;
matrix table; 
table.reserve(2); 
table[0].reserve(1); table[1].reserve(1);

table[0][0] = 'c';
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vector<>::reserve(x)` - не создает сам по себе элементы, просто резервирует память.
Нужно писать:

```
table.push_back(vector<string>()); // помещаем пустой вектор в table
table[0].push_back("c"); // вмеcто table[0][0] = 'c' - помещаем строку "с" в первую строку table
```

Пример

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(5);
std::cout << v.size(); // выведет 0!
```

Кстати, у `std::string` нет конструктора с единственным аргументом типа `char`, поэтому нужно использовать двойные кавычки.

```
table.push_back(vector<string>());
table[0].push_back("a"); table[0].push_back("b");
table.push_back(vector<string>());
table[1].push_back("c"); table[1].push_back("d");
// table:
// a b
// c d
table[2].push_back("e"); // ошибка, строки 2 - еще нет
table[0][2] = "new string"; // ошибка, в строке 0 - всего 2 элемента
```

Comment: спасибо! table[0].push_back("c") - так будет заполняться левый столбец? table[1].push_back("c") - а так правый?

Comment: @ensiferum, я бы назвал это скорее "строками". Обычно - первый индекс - номер строки, второй - номер столбца.

Comment: @ensiferum, дополнил ответ, для ясности

Comment: все понятно, спасибо большое!

Comment: @andy.37, у строки таки есть конструктор с аргументом типа char - string (size_t n, char c); Первым параметром, очевидно, нужно передавать 1.

Comment: @gbg "единственным аргументом типа char". `string s = 'x'` - ошибка.

Comment: @andy.37 я написал - КОНСТРУКТОР, а не оператор присваивания.

Comment: @gbg Вы полагаете, что строчки `string s("x");` и `string s = "x";` чем-то отличаются? И во второй вызывается оператор присваивания? Вы не правы.

Comment: @andy.37 я привел прототип конструктора, у которого ДВА параметра, который позволяет создать строку из char.

Comment: @gbg, да я то Вас понял. Я имел в виду, что в тексте вопроса строка `table[0][0] = 'c';` - в любом случае ошибочна, независимо от существования `table[0]` и `table[0][0]`. Из-за одинарных кавычек. И поэтому явно написал, что string - не имеет конструктора с *единственным* аргументом char.